# Add multiple keys to plist dictionary [pre-populate it from an excel file beforehand]

Tags: objective-c, plist, nsmutabledictionary

Is there an easy way to add multiple keys in a plist and pre-populate?

EDIT: Basically what I want to do is convert my excel document to a plist with the following structure:

I got a simple plist structure:

```
<key>Alpha</key>
<string>This is the letter alpha</string>
<key>Beta</key>
<string>This is the letter beta</string>
```

And many data (over 1000) in an excel table:

Column one  |  Column 2

"This the key"  | " this is the string"
etc.

Thanks

Comment: But surely the `plist` is an `NSMutableDictionary` when in memory?  Also we need to know how the excel columns are stored in memory.

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain that well. I need to pre-populate the plist. I just find it too difficult to add these data one by one...

Comment: Sounds like a job for python.

Comment: Any idea how to do that!

Comment: What do you mean under 'too difficult to add these data one by one'? Is setting [dictionary setObject:forKey:] too slow?

Comment: @Nickolay Olshevsky Please see EDITED question

Comment: he doesn't want to do it at runtime.

Comment: Oh, I see. Doubt that such question should be on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to more columns to your Excel sheet. On the first row, add these formulas to the two new cells:

```
="<key>" & A1 & "</key>"
="<string>" & B1 & "</string>"
```

Then copy the cells into the remaining cells of the new columns. Now you basically have the contents of your plist file. Select it and copy it into the text editor. The key and the value will be on the same line. But that's not relevant, it's just formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I create an add-in Excel function to convert ranges to plist (download the Excel with macro-enabled file from here: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9SJEsPaoCzbdFpqMVNEaTZMQUk/edit).

Comment: what do these macros do exactly? not sure what you are trying to achieve here... is this some sort of a prank?